# Qt Android: How to show the native file dialog?

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5, qfiledialog

I'm not sure if it is possible, but currently, when I show an open file dialog:

```
QString file = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this);
```

The dialog shown is not the native dialog for Android.

Instead, it looks like this (it's also not maximized):

[image]

I'm using Qt 5.2.0 for Android.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt/Necessitas - reasonable QFileDialog replacement/skin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079406/qt-necessitas-reasonable-qfiledialog-replacement-skin)

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.2.0, which is **not Necessitas**, keep in mind. This is an official port, while Necessitas is unofficial, and also an older release.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov: necessitas is qt 4, and the question has the Qt 5 tag as well as the reference to it.

Comment: @sashoalm: widgets are ancient, and mostly desktop technology... It is certain that you do not get lotta better user experience out of it. Why not QtQuick2/QtQuickControls or at least the C++ scene graph?

Comment: I'll try to see if a Qt Quick project will have a native dialog, maybe that's the reason I don't have a native dialog.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to show a file dialog in Qt Quick.

Comment: @Laszlo Papp Replacing widgets with graphics view framework is highly questionable. Widgets (and QtQuick) is a general-purpose module, while GVF is convenient only in certain tasks.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov: you are still confusing Qt 4 with Qt 5. In Qt 5, QtQuick2 is _not_ actually based on QGV. In fact, the whole point was to change that. :)

Comment: @PavelStrakhov Btw, can you retract that close vote? It is possible to do it.

Comment: @Laszlo Papp I didn't say anything about QtQuick2 being based on QGV. Actually, this fact doesn't matter for our subject at all.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov: "Replacing widgets with graphics view framework is highly questionable" -> That was the reply to "Use QML instead of widgets".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible in general by using Ministro as a workaround for now.

See the following bugreport for details:

[No native controls on Qt 5.2 for Android, not in widgets nor in quick application](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-35081)

The QFileDialog seems to be specified by the QPlatformTheme which is supposed to be implemented.

Comment: I made the application install Ministro following this answer -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15735878/492336. Unfortunately, installing it did not make the application use the native dialog.

Comment: It seems Ministro does not make the application look native at all, and [one of the comments](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-35081?focusedCommentId=225929&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-225929) in the link you provided suggests it wasn't implemented. OK, well, maybe in the future it will be possible.

Comment: @sashoalm: hmm, you seem to think that QtQuickControls are QtWidgets, whereas they are not. That comment states the future plan of QtQuickControls, however QFileDialog is in QtWidgets.

Comment: My application doesn't use Qt Quick, and Ministro still doesn't make it look native, in fact, it screws up the theme so the checkboxes don't show at all (only their text shows).

Comment: I haven't specified a platform theme anywhere, I just set my application to [use Ministro](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15735878/492336). How do I specify a platform theme?

Comment: @sashoalm: just read it this morning, http://www.kdab.com/using-qt-make-native-android-apps/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=using-qt-make-native-android-apps

Comment: @lpapp The bug is now closed, would you mind updating the question?