# How prevent errors on windows when i use Qt Android Extras C++ Classes

Tags: android, c++, qt, c++11, qtandroidextras

I used the solution of below question for open file on Android.

[Qt/Necessitas - reasonable QFileDialog replacement/skin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079406/qt-necessitas-reasonable-qfiledialog-replacement-skin)

But it works just on android,this codes ([Qt Android Extras C++ Classes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-module.html)) don't run on windows?

for example i got the below errors?

```
#include<QAndroidJniObject>
#include<QtAndroid>
#include<QAndroidActivityResultReceiver>
```

> Cannot open include file: 'QAndroidJniObject': No such file or directory

I used this for solving

```
#if defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)
#include<QAndroidJniObject>
#include<QtAndroid>
#include<QAndroidActivityResultReceiver>
#endif
```

but when i used this I have got another errors?

```
 class ResultReceiver:public QAndroidActivityResultReceiver//error :'QAndroidActivityResultReceiver': base class undefined
{
    AndroidFileDialog *_dialog;

public:
    ResultReceiver(AndroidFileDialog *dialog);

    virtual ~ResultReceiver();
    void handleActivityResult(int receiverRequestCode, int resultCode, const QAndroidJniObject &data);
    QString uriToPath(QAndroidJniObject uri);
};
```

> 'QAndroidActivityResultReceiver': base class undefined

Comment: Mohsen, How do you expect a class part of Android Extras [QAndroidActivityResultReceiver](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidactivityresultreceiver.html) to work under windows,

Comment: @MohammadKanan I want to run my application on android and windows.I want this solution for android ,and now it works,and i want to use `FileDialog` for windows.but how run my application on windows when i want to use this for android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `ResultReceiver` inherits `QAndroidActivityResultReceiver` (from Android Extras) which you correctly stopped including for windows OS, thus the error.

You must have 2 variants of `ResultReceiver` class, one for Windows, another for Android. When you design it for Windows you should not inherit `QAndroidActivityResultReceiver` and use `QFileDialog`. 
In the same way you solved the `import` issues with Qt pre-processor,  you could define `ResultReceiver` class , for *example*:

```
#if defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)

class AndroidFileDialog : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
  ...
private:
    class ResultReceiver : public QAndroidActivityResultReceiver {
        AndroidFileDialog *_dialog;
        ...
    };
    ...
    ...
};
#else
class ResultReceiver // Here do not inherit classes from Android Extras
{
   QFileDialog *_dialog; // use standard Qt C++ classes 
   ...
   ...
};
#endif //Q_OS_ANDROID
```

Answer (score 1):

That's understandable, the project is compiled in accordance with your *.pro file which includes all the project files. So you try to compile Android related files on Windows and so you get an error. You should include/exclude files in your *.pro file, according to the target OS, for example:

```
SOURCES += \
    common.cpp

HEADERS += \
    common.h

win32 {
    SOURCES += \
    winfile.cpp

    HEADERS += \
    winfile.h

    LIBS += -lwin
}

android {
    SOURCES += \
    androidfile.cpp

    HEADERS += \
    androidfile.h

    LIBS += -landroid
}
```

and so unnecessary files will not be compiled/linked

Comment: it still don't work ,i get `No such file or directory` error .and my project don't compile,

Comment: "still don't work" says nothing about the problem. You probably did something wrong. Using conditionally including in .pro and preprocessor directives definitely can help.